# What is the error in this SQL command?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the error in this SQL command

```
select account_id,fname,lname ,
    (select email from account where id=account_id) as email 
from user_account 
where account_id in (
       select destination_id 
       from friendship 
       where source_id=$user_id) 
    and (concat(fname,lname) like '%a%' or email like '%a%')
```

Where `email` is a column in `account` table

The error message is : `Unknown column email`

I want to get email and test it same as fname+lname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your table `user_account` doesn't have a column named `email` referenced in your WHERE clause. Try this with a `JOIN` instead:

```
   select ua.account_id,
          ua.fname,
          ua.lname, 
          a.email 
from user_account ua
inner join  account a where ua.id = a.account_id
and a.account_id  in ( select destination_id from friendship where source_id=$user_id) 
and (concat(fname,lname) like '%a%' or email like '%a%');
```

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting your query for legibility:

```
SELECT account_id, fname, lname,
       (SELECT email FROM account WHERE id = account_id) AS email
  FROM user_account 
 WHERE account_id IN (SELECT destination_id FROM friendship WHERE source_id = $user_id)
   AND (CONCAT(fname, lname) LIKE '%a%' OR email LIKE '%a%')
```

The most probable cause of trouble is that the only table that the column `email` can refer to in the main WHERE clause is `user_account`, but the `email` column is only found in the `account` table.

The simplest fix is to remove the sub-query in the select-list and use a regular join instead:

```
SELECT u.account_id, u.fname, u.lname, a.email
  FROM user_account AS u
  JOIN account      AS a ON a.id = u.account_id
 WHERE account_id IN (SELECT destination_id
                        FROM friendship AS f
                       WHERE f.source_id = $user_id)
   AND (CONCAT(u.fname, u.lname) LIKE '%a%' OR a.email LIKE '%a%');
```

I'm assuming that `$user_id` is an input value and the notation makes sense in your system; it is not generally valid in SQL.

It is not clear that there is much benefit to the IN clause; that too could be made into a join with the other tables.

Comment: Out of topic question: Your reputation is 104k !! 
That's great, but how you may advantage from it ?

Comment: There could be several answers...(1) I don't; (2) I can do editing and revising and all sorts of things that newcomers can't; (3) it keeps my brain agile; (4) it gives me something to obsess over; (5) it gives me something to do when I should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I assue that your id in Accout table is same as Account_id in User_Account and also the Destination_id in friendship tables.

```
select ua.account_id,
       ua.fname,
       ua.lname, 
       a.email 
from user_account ua
inner join  account a where ua.id = a.account_id
and a.account_id  
in ( select destination_id from friendship where source_id=$user_id) and (concat(fname,lname) like '%a%' or email like '%a%')
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error in this SQL command

```
select account_id,fname,lname ,
(select email from account where id=account_id) as email from user_account 
where account_id 
  in ( select destination_id from friendship where source_id=$user_id) and          (concat(fname,lname) like '%a%' or email like '%a%')
```

The problem is that, in the following syntax, **email** is a table alias, not a column name

```
(select email from account where id=account_id) as email
```

It looks like you've already got a better approach from p.campell though

Comment: I don't think 'email' is a table alias; it is a column from table account, and the result of the sub-query in the select-list is itself given a (column) alias of 'email', which is actually the alias it would have without the AS clause.  That sub-query must return a single row, please note.